# Как оформить ответ человека на вопрос, заканчивающийся многоточием?

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста, многоточие

Продолжите фразу: «Для меня мама – это...» (вопрос журналиста). Ответ интервьюируемого: ...всё. Так правильно оформить ответ человека или надо с прописной?

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю, надо без многоточий и с прописной, ведь просят продолжить, значит, нас интересует само продолжение, а многоточие осталось там:

— Продолжите фразу: «Для меня мама – это...»
— Всё.